# Which browsers send "Expect: 100-Continue" request header?

Tags: browsers, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I just want to make sure which browsers send the `Expect: 100-Continue` header? So that until the server responds with a `100 Continue` HTTP status, no data should be sent.

Comment: This is unclear. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Itai, There is special header in HTTP called Expect 100 Continue. When a browser send this header until server returns 100 continue, client will not send any data to server

Comment: Just to clarify... the browser sends an `Expect:` header with a value of `100-Continue`, the server then responds with an HTTP status code of `100 Continue` if applicable. I don't _think_ any browser sends this header automatically, this is down to your code - IMHO.